# Ruby on Rails Each do method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, keyword, meta

I'm trying to do my keyword metatags. I want to make the following as keywords.

```
- @document.category.ancestors.each do |category|
= category.description  "
```

The above works fine on its own in the view, but how can I maybe move that into a helper so I can use it as a method so that I can insert it into the array below? Or is there another way I can do this?

```
:keywords => [category.descriptions go here]
```

Comment: `@document.ancestors.collect{|c| c.description}`. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an instance method under your Document model that returns an array of the category descriptions:

```
def category_descriptions
  self.ancestors.collect { |a| a.description }
end
```

Then wherever you have a document object just call .category_descriptions on it and it will return you the array of descriptions.

Comment: I replaced "self" with "category" and it worked! Thanks a heap!

Comment: No problem, good catch on that one I forgot to add the association of category.